# Using JsonLoader in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2, bigdata

```
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/flume/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/flume/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/flume/elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/flume/json-simple-1.1.1.jar';

load_tweets = LOAD '/user/flume/tweets/' USING 
com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
```

Even after registering the 4 JARs required for using JsonLoader in PIG, I'm getting the below error.

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not 
resolve com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader using imports: [, 
java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

grunt> hadoop fs -ls /user/flume    
...... /user/flume/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar
...... /user/flume/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar
...... /user/flume/elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar
...... /user/flume/json-simple-1.1.1.jar
...... /user/flume/tweets
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your JAR files didn't get registered.

> using imports: [, 
>   java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Are you running Pig in local mode? `pig -x local`? Otherwise, are your files placed on HDFS?

If not local and you're reading from HDFS, upload your JAR files there, and use

```
REGISTER 'hdfs:///path/file.jar'
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use Spark for JSON files

Comment: No. I'm using pig in mapreduce mode and my jars are in HDFS.
I even register the 4th Jar - elephant-bird-core-4.1 
Still didn't work.

Comment: That's correct. The distributed mappers cannot all read your local filesystem. And use `REGISTER 'hdfs:///path/file.jar'`

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: I placed all my Jars in HDFS, and then tried to run. Still not working :(

Comment: Same error? Different message? It should list the package names if the jars imported correctly.

Comment: Same error. When I register, it doesn't give any message at all. Just the next grunt prompt.

Comment: You're running line by line, or a pig file?

Comment: Not a pig file. Running commands on the shell (line by line).

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the updated code and the `hadoop fs -ls` of the folder you're reading from?

Comment: You had 3 before? Can you try a [mcve]? Perhaps making your own jar (or python) files for UDF and registering those? I don't see anything wrong with what you have done